# How can I delay dropbox from starting, but not disable it?

Tags: startup, login, dropbox

When I log into my user account on Ubuntu 10.10, there is a unsatisfying delay before my system becomes usable.  Even launching a terminal, I have to wait a few seconds before the bash prompt appears.   During this start-up period, the top process seems to be dropbox.   I'm not sure what it's doing exactly (functionality is still fine as far as I can see), but I do know it really doesn't need to be doing it while I'm waiting for desktop to appear.  (This is the standard Ubuntu with Gnome desktop, by the way.)

What I would like to do is to be able to have a static or even dependency-based delay for dropbox to start.  It would be nice if it waited for, e.g., 10 minutes, or for my browser tabs to load and a typing pause.  Then it could churn away on file status or cache-chewing, and I would be happy.

Is there a way to do this?   Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, disable Dropbox from starting on login.
Open up the DropBox preferences and uncheck *Start Dropbox on system startup*:

[image]

Now we will manually add Dropbox to the list of applications that run on login.
 Open up *System ➜ Preferences ➜ Startup Applications* and click on *Add* to add a new entry.

Use `Dropbox` for the name and `bash -c "sleep 10m && dropbox start -i"` for the command, and then click *Add* to save it.

[image]

That's it, now Dropbox won't start until 10 minutes after you have logged in.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. For some reason, the command reverts to the default after a reboot.

Comment: @Alex, see my updated answer. It turns out dropbox overwrites the `.desktop` autostart file every time it is run.

Comment: Very useful, but remove the _- i_ option in order to avoid dropbox reinstalling itself at startup

Comment: Worked for transmission, but dropbox just didn't start. Bit unusual.

Answer (score 6):

I found myself having the same problem recently and the way I fixed it is a mixture of the two answers, the reason being that Dropbox would rewrite the launcher *dropbox.desktop* entry in *~/.config/autostart/* whether I had it ticked to start on startup or not. 
So here are the steps you can take if you find yourself in a similar situation:

- Untick the box to start on system startup (see first pick on Onalemon's answer)
- Create a file that will be your custom application launcher in *~/.config/autostart/*. You can use

  `gedit ~/.config/autostart/theNameOfYourCustomLauncher.desktop`.

Whatever you want to call it, just don't call it *dropbox.desktop*

- paste in the following code using your own settings for the *Name* and the *X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay*

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=NameOfYourCustomLauncher
  GenericName=File Synchronizer
  Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
  Exec=dropbox start
  X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=15 
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Icon=dropbox
  Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
  StartupNotify=false
  ```

All that is left is for you to create a new startup launcher:
I'm using the Gnome Shell, so I can just go to *Applications ➜ System Tools ➜ Startup Applications* or run `gnome-session-properties` on terminal and fill in the text boxes:

```
Name: NameOfYourCustomLauncher
Command: dropbox start -i
Comment: YourComment
```

And that's it! After a restart it worked just fine.

Answer (score 5):

**Delaying autostart with inbuilt delay option**

This one works without the need for a script or `sleep`. Open your dropbox autostart entry in a text editor:

```
gedit ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop
```

Append the following line to the file:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=foo
```

where `foo` is the time in seconds you want to delay the application launch by, for instance

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=60
```

would delay the application start by one minute.

Save the file, relog and you should see the effects.

Comment: This works fine once, but unfortunately Dropbox overwrites the .desktop file at startup. Making this file readonly with `chmod a-w dropbox.desktop` seems to solve this issue.