# How can I delay a specific program on startup?

Tags: configuration, startup, cairo-dock

How to delay a program such as cairo-dock (No openGL) or Firefox?

Sometimes programs crash when started with other startup apps. I want programs to start 10 seconds late to avoid a crash.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/22512/how-can-i-delay-dropbox-from-starting-but-not-disable-it

Answer (score 59):

**Delaying autostart with inbuilt delay option**

---

**Note**: Only works with desktop sessions that recognize the `X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay`parameter (e.g. Unity, Unity2D, GNOME). This will not work for LXDE, XFCE, KDE, etc.

---

With this solution there's no need for a script or sleep. Head to your autostart folder:

```
nautilus ~/.config/autostart
```

Find the `.desktop` file that corresponds with your application and open it in a text editor, e.g. `gedit`:

```
gedit ~/.config/autostart/application.desktop
```

Append the following line to the file:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=foo
```

where `foo` is the time in seconds you want to delay the application launch by, e.g.:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=60
```

Save the file, relog and you should see the effects.

Comment: This works very well in both ubuntu 12.04 and in 12.10-development release using Gnome-shell 3.6

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Is there a website or man page to find documentation for GNOME parameters? I searched in  `gnome-session` man page but could not find them.

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
bash -c "sleep 10 && firefox"
```

Comment: 10x a lot, why does just *sleep 10 && firefox* not work?

Answer (score 6):

You could try to change the command to this:

```
sleep 10 && firefox
```

Some people say it works, some say it doesn't, if this is your case, and it does not work, you can try with:

```
xterm -e 'sleep 10 && firefox'
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to use this to get it to work for skype: `sh -c "sleep 10 && skype &"` in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Make a startup command using https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/139749 . Then you can add delay by opening `~/.config/autostart` and edit related file. You should add the following commands:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=10
```

Comment: you're repeating the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution by @Noraj works well for Ubuntu 18.04. Adding a couple of practical examples for Google Drive sync via Insync, and Synology cloud-drive. I don't want them to delay the startup.

For google-drive:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Insync
GenericName=Insync
Comment=Launch Insync
Icon=insync
Categories=Network;
Exec=insync start
TryExec=insync
Terminal=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=60
```

And for cloud-drive:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Synology Drive Client
Comment=Synology Drive Client
Exec=synology-drive autostart
Icon=/opt/Synology/SynologyDrive/images/ico_72_cloud_station.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=75
```

Both files locate at `$HOME/.config/autostart` if you installed the applications and chose to make them *start at login*.