# Sleep command not working with start up applications

Tags: 11.04, startup

I am trying to add a delay at start up for a few applications using the sleep command.  For example: I'm trying `sleep 5; tomboy` which works in terminal, but doesn't work when I add it to the command field in the "Startup Applications" section of the system settings.

With the sleep command, the commands don't seem to execute at all.  Is there another command I should be using to create a delay?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The startup applications line probably doesn't invoke a shell. Try setting it to run in a terminal. Then, change it to: `bash -c 'sleep 5; exec tomboy'`.

Warning: This is all untested.

Comment: You probably don't want to set it to run in a terminal since you don't want a useless terminal window hanging around.

Comment: @psusi @mssever This is working perfectly. It's not launching a terminal window, everything starts up like it should, just now with the delay. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Use `X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=5` in .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart/tomboy.desktop. see here:[How can I delay a specific program on startup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28685/how-can-i-delay-a-specific-program-on-startup)