# How to delay the start of an application during startup to reduce total booting time?

Tags: scripts, 12.10, startup, samsung, boot-time

I have an application installed on my Samsung NP-RV509 which makes the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work properly.

I have determined that the startup of this application is the reason for almost 30 extra seconds of booting time.

Can I write a shell/python script (I, myself, can't actually do this as I don't know shell/python programming) that will introduce a delay by maybe using a loop or something and then start the above application?  Shall I add/apply this script in startup apps?

This should effectively simulate the running of that program at startup, but it would be delayed in actuality.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28685/how-can-i-delay-a-specific-program-on-startup/ ; also you might want to use [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28685/how-can-i-delay-a-specific-program-on-startup/195036#195036) instead of sleep, if you are using a DE like Unity or GNOME.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a delay time with `sleep` command.

`man sleep` for more info .

**Example**

I want to startup a program with delay of 10 seconds. 
I create an entry in the startup applications with this in command field

`sleep 10;/usr/bin/<program name>`

**Example 2**

I want to create a script with the delay (sleep) option and add this script to startup applications

`gedit delayscript.sh`

and I add these lines

```
#!/bin/bash 

sleep 10 
/usr/bin/<program name>
```

save the script and give it executable permissions

`chmod +x delayscript.sh`

and add it to startup applications (command field) with full path

`/home/username/delayscript.sh`

Comment: is this non blocking? (i.e. will this hold up the whole startup process?)

Comment: No, it won't hold the whole startup process. It will delay to execute this specific script only.

Answer (score 1):

while this is a great answer:

```
sleep 30; <app-name>
```

It does have one hidden downside: if you ever want to kill the delayed app before it starts to run, it's not anywhere in ps -ef; instead all you see is "sleep 30". And, if you kill that sleep command, rather than preventing the delayed app from running it just makes the app run immediately. So I suggest this alternate script (delay) which, if killed, prevents the delayed app from running:

```
#!/bin/bash
# easily killable sleep
sleep $1
shift
$@
```

example:

delay 10m rebuild-database

now, if you decide for some reason to prevent the database from being rebuilt, you can kill the shell script.