# How to disable 3 finger drag on macbook air trackpad. I'm a novice with command line

Tags: 12.10, trackpad, gestures

So I read the other answer for this question but I really was hoping to get a more basic explanation that would make sense to an ubuntu novice.

I am running 12.10 on a 2011 macbook air and love it generally but three finger drag activating whenever I try to re-size a window is driving me completely insane. There seems to be a way to disable it, [How can I disable the multitouch gestures in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu) but I lost the last contributor's advice at "...create a shell script" and the other answers didn't seem to work.

wrt my familiarity with the command line I understand generally how to add repositories and update installed packages. Kind of. That's about it.

Any help for a noob here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In the post you're quoting, the right way of doing things is to use synclient.

The command line posted in [How can I disable the multitouch gestures in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu) should do the trick. If you want to test it, just execute this line in a terminal :

```
synclient ClickFinger3=2 && synclient TapButton3=2
```

If the behaviour is OK with these parameters, you have to execute this piece of code at each system startup. This is done easily. First, create a text file that you can name touchpad.sh for instance. Inside, you put this code :

```
 #!/bin/sh
 sleep 10;
 synclient ClickFinger3=2;
 synclient TapButton3=2;
```

The sleep command is to delay the call of synclient. If it's called too early in the startup process it will have no effect. Try larger numbers than 10 if this doesn't work.

Then, you must grant execution rights to this script and execute it at each boot. See this page for information on how to do this : [how can i write a shell script that will run at startup and introduce a delay in the start of an application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206432/how-can-i-write-a-shell-script-that-will-run-at-startup-and-introduce-a-delay-in)

Ben