# How do I delay a startup application in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I want Firefox to start automatically when I start Lubuntu. I have the LXSession Configuration app installed. In it, I've tried entering all the suggestions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/28685/17041), such as:

```
bash -c "sleep 10 && firefox"

sleep 10 && firefox

xterm -e 'sleep 10 && firefox'

sh -c "sleep 10 && skype &"
```

For all of them, they work on the command line, but not when I enter them in the LXSession Configuration interface.

If I enter `firefox` by itself, it launches when Lubuntu starts.

I'm guessing all the sleep commands above only work in Ubuntu. How to I get a program to delay when autostarting in Lubuntu?

Extra note: The reason I want to delay Firefox is because I autoconnect to a VPN, and it takes a while for the VPN to complete connecting. I need Firefox to start after the VPN connection is complete, so if there is any way to force one program (like Firefox) to start upon completion of some other event (network manager completing a connection), that would work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Create a file `$HOME/.config/upstart/firefox-with-delay.conf`

Content:

```
start on desktop-start
stop on desktop-end

script
    sleep 30
    firefox 
end script
```

More info:

http://ifdeflinux.blogspot.de/2013/04/upstart-user-sessions-in-ubuntu-raring.html

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/