# Autostart a script after desktop loads

Tags: autostart

I am trying to autostart a script after the desktop loads. I'm running Xubuntu.

I already tried putting a link into /ect/profile, and copying a .desktop into /.config/autostart/.

While this launches the script, it loads before the desktop does and then the desktop does not load until I close the script. 
How can I make it launch only after the desktop loads?

Thank you!

EDIT: The script opens a java app that needs to run indefinitely.

Comment: is there a specific element of the desktop the script should wait for? Also Why is the script not closing?

Comment: Did you try Upstart http://askubuntu.com/a/468698/265974 ?

Comment: @Xubu-Tur Thanks, that works perfectly.