# Megasync stops syncing automatically

Tags: 18.04, mega

I was certain the megasync client was uploading all files created in a dedicated folder, but I just noticed that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that what most probably happened is that the dedicated location is not selected to be synced anymore.

Checking that option [fixes the problem](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAsync/issues/223#issuecomment-460208619) for the moment.

[image]

The probable cause of this is that an error occurred at some point in relation to the source location being on a drive that was not mounted anymore - as said [here](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAsync/issues/223#issuecomment-460234629).

In my case the cause was that the megasync client was starting before the mounting of the drive on which the Megasync dedicated folder is located. An error takes place after which the megasync client *should* resume syncing: for some reason it doesn't sometimes.

To avoid that error the client can be set to start with a delay (as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/28695/925128)):

```
bash -c "sleep 5 && megasync"
```

[image]

Also, we need to be sure that the drive where the synced folder is located must be mounted at startup. I use Disks (gnome-disks) for this purpose, as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/588034/925128).

[image]